# How to fix SELECT statement to return duplicates

Tags: sql, postgresql

Currently I am trying to return a three table join to find duplicate track titles that are in my a "track" table, and also return the track number | cd title from the other joined tables.  My select statement is currently returning all the information from the joined tables but its not showing only the duplicates.

I have also tried using a group by and having clause to try to find a COUNT of comptitle.  When I tried that it returned the an empty table.

My Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE composition (compid, comptitle,...,
    PRIMARY KEY (compid),...);

CREATE TABLE recording (rcdid,..., compid,
    PRIMARY KEY (rcdid, compid),...);

CREATE TABLE cd (cdid, cdtitle,..., 
    PRIMARY KEY(cdid),...);

CREATE TABLE track (cdid, trknum,..., rcdid, compid,
    PRIMARY KEY (cdid, trknum),...);
```

My statement:

```
SELECT comptitle, trknum, cdtitle
    FROM track JOIN recording ON track.rcdid = recording.rcdid
    JOIN composition ON recording.compid = composition.compid
    JOIN cd ON cd.cdid = track.cdid;
```

Output expected | actual:

```
EXPECTED:
      comptitle      | trknum | cdtitle     
--------------------------------------------
 Cousin Mary         | 2      | Giant Steps 
 Cousin Mary         | 10     | Giant Steps 
 Giant Steps         | 1      | Giant Steps 
 Giant Steps         | 8      | Giant Steps 

ACTUAL:
         comptitle          | trknum |   cdtitle   
----------------------------+--------+-------------
 Giant Steps                | 8      | Giant Steps
 Giant Steps                | 1      | Giant Steps
 Stomp of King Porter       | 1      | Swing
 Sing a Study in Brown      | 2      | Swing
 Cousin Mary                | 14     | Swing
 Cousin Mary                | 10     | Giant Steps
```

Comment: Wrap it into `GROUP BY comptitle` and `HAVING COUNT(*)>1`.

Comment: @PM77-1 When I do that it makes me group in trknum and cdtitle. Then when I do that it gives me an empty table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT comptitle, trknum, cdtitle
FROM (SELECT comptitle, trknum, cdtitle,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY comptitle) as cnt
      FROM track t JOIN
           recording r
           ON t.rcdid = r.rcdid JOIN
           composition c
           ON r.compid = c.compid JOIN
           cd 
           ON cd.cdid = t.cdid
     ) t
WHERE cnt >= 2
ORDER BY cnt, comptitle;
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a subquery to first find the duplicated track titles in `track` table, then join this to the other tables. This subquery would look like:

```
  SELECT rcdid, COUNT(*) AS number
  FROM track
  GROUP BY rcdid
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Now, depending on what database engine you're using, you may be able to use a CTE which would make it more readable. If that is your case, you could try:

```
WITH CTE_DuplicatedTracks AS (
  SELECT rcdid, COUNT(*) AS number
  FROM track
  GROUP BY rcdid
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT
  c.comptitle,
  t.trknum,
  cd.cdtitle
FROM
  CTE_DuplicatedTracks dt
  JOIN track t ON
    dt.rcdid = t.rcdid
  JOIN recording r ON
    t.rcdid = r.rcdid
  JOIN composition c ON
    r.compid = c.compid
  JOIN cd
    ON cd.cdid = t.cdid;
```

If your engine does not support CTEs:

```
SELECT
  c.comptitle,
  t.trknum,
  cd.cdtitle
FROM
  (
    SELECT rcdid, COUNT(*) as number
    FROM track
    GROUP BY rcdid
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  ) dt
  JOIN track t ON
    dt.rcdid = t.rcdid
  JOIN recording r ON
    t.rcdid = r.rcdid
  JOIN composition c ON
    r.compid = c.compid
  JOIN cd
    ON cd.cdid = t.cdid;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Although this doesn't give me the expected output I needed,  I can work with this to get my answer. But again thanks for helping understand sql a little better.